# Angular StateParams never changes when Url params change?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an Ionic app, and have a very basic routing scenario, I am trying to go to a detail page with an id param, which is optional.

Navigation occurs succesfully everytime, but when I try and access the value in the controller it remains the same as whatever the first time request was.

For e.g navigating to `playlists/1` would output `Object {playlistId: "1"}` then when navigating to `playlists/2` it would again output `Object {playlistId: "1"}`

I have tried so many things, but can't find the issue help appreciated.

My route setup looks like this:

```
  .state('app.single', {
    url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl',
         resolve: {
           playlistId: function($state, $stateParams) {
             return $stateParams.playlistId; // note this changes every time. I put this here for testing.
           }
         }
      }
    }
  })
```

And my controller:

```
.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

  console.log($stateParams);
```

Navigating using:

```
<div class="card">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap" ui-sref="app.single({playlistId: undefined})">
        Test
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap" ui-sref="app.single({playlistId: 1})">
        Test 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap" ui-sref="app.single({playlistId: 2})">
        Test 2
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're hitting the cache. You can disable it by adding `cache:false` to your state:

```
.state('app.single', {
    cache: false, //add this
    url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl',
         resolve: {
           playlistId: function($state, $stateParams) {
             return $stateParams.playlistId; // note this changes every time. I put this here for testing.
           }
         }
      }
    }
  })
```